# Nokogiri returning variable name instead of actual data on website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am fetching data from a website. I need to fetch a text inside h1 tag. when I inspect the element , inside that h1 tag there is a text. But when I fetch using Nokogiri, there is a variable name in that h1 tag.

```
content = open('https://example.com').read
html = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
html.css('h1#egift-refresh-online-number-desktop').text
```

when I inspect in chrome i found

[image]

But when I view the source of that page, I saw

[image]

I need to extract the actual value not the variable name. How can I do that with Nokogiri? If there is any method for doing this?

Comment: Everything looks good. Can you please provide the URL from where you are trying to read the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri is just a simple XML/HTML parser and is not the right tool for this job.

What you have fetched looks like a Handlebars template (or one of its many offshots) and `{{ ecardDetails.cardCardnumber }}` is just a placeholder in the HTML file that is replaced with actual data by JavaScript possibly after doing an AJAX request.

Nokogiri does not execute JavaScript as its not a browser.

[Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) is a DSL which is mostly used for acceptance testing which when used with the correct driver (like selenium or webkit) can automate a browser and thus scrape pages that rely on JavaScript.

Comment: With gems capybara, selenium-webdriver, webdrivers, I fetched data using headless chrome and I got the actual data.